# iPhone app distribution building warning: This bundle is invalid

Tags: ios, build, warnings, distribution

When i build my app in Xcode I got the warning below which prohibits me from uploading my app to the App Store:

> This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not
>   formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed,
>   followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier:
>   com.companyname.appname (-19053)

I have tried to change bundle indentifier to "85B9GK2627.com.companyname.appname". But I get the same warnings. Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When XCode says to change it to "XXXXX.com.companyname.appname" it means you should actually use the values you supplied when creating the app on iTunesConnect. ".com.companyname.appname" is just an example.

Comment: I don't think it has bussness with iTunesConnect ,because I got warnings when building a distribution before I upload my app. what is the currect app id should i supply."XXXXX.com.companyname.appname" or "com.companyname.appname"? but neither works

Comment: Are you using Entitlements.plist - for uploading to TestFlight? If yes, then you can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: thank you very much.I fixed this by add the file entitlements.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the bundle identifier from portal which you have used in your distribution provisioning profile and add that to info.plist. Then perform clean and build.

Comment: I have tried. I copy the App ID in Distribution Provisioning Profiles and then past to info.plist for key  "Bundle Identifier",I have performed clean alse. but it doesn't work unfortunatily.I　even removed Distribution Certificate and recreated it.